# Pandas loc uses inclusive ranges and iloc uses exclusive on upper side

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are myriad posts, along with `pandas`' own warnings, about performing slices of slices, something like:

```py
>>> df['b'][1]
```

So, the better practice is:

```py
>>> df.loc[1,'b']
```

But I (we) often have to ignore the actual *values* of row indices because some actions can alter or recreate them.  So when writing functions or methods, I want to use `loc` because names are easier for columns, but `iloc` to deal with this inconsistency of row names.

---

I thought a nice compromise would be:

```py
>>> df.loc[df.index[1],'b']
```

That works. But then I noticed this strange issue with indexing:

## Slices are Inconsistent Between `loc` and `iloc`!

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'b': [4.2, 8.8, 1, 1], 'c': [5, 10, 2, 9]})
>>> df
     b   c
0  4.2   5
1  8.8  10
2  1.0   2
3  1.0   9

>>> df.loc[df.index[1:2],:]
     b   c
1  8.8  10
>>> df.loc[1:2,:]
     b   c
1  8.8  10
2  1.0   2
```

I was very confused by this, until I realized:

1. `iloc` is *exclusive* in ranges, like most of Python.  Eg,

   ```py
   >>> df.iloc[1:2,:]
        b   c
   1  8.8  10
   ```
2. `loc` is *inclusive* in ranges, capturing all "names" provided.  Eg,

   ```py
   >>> df.loc[1:2,:]
    b   c
   1  8.8  10
   2  1.0   2
   ```
3. `Series`' `index` acts like `iloc`, being *exclusive*.

## What to Do?

I now know this, and hopefully will not screw up again.

***But is this the right behavior***?

I can post to `pandas`' GitHub bugs, but I wanted to hear why what seems so strange to me might have good logic.

I understand that ranges are typically exclusive, and that being exclusive on *names* is weird.

But maybe there is a better third alternative, like a ***version of `loc` that allows one to specify that the rows are numeric (`iloc`-like) and the columns are names***?  After all, this is the behavior that we all want 95% of the time.